# Kendo window change scrolling to have static update/cancel buttons

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP MVC and a current release of Kendo.  If I add too much information to a Kendo window, it scrolls vertically.  This hides the cancel/update buttons that get generated at the bottom. I need these shown. The user should not need to scroll to hit cancel.  How can I make the "form-horizontal" scroll and the "k-window" not scroll?

Full Window:

[image: Full window]

Window with scrolling:

[image: Scroll window]

Code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.CompanyList)
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns => {
           columns.Bound(o => o.Company.Name);
           columns.Bound(o => o.Company.DealerId);
           columns.Bound(o => o.Company.CityState).Title("City, " + stateTitle);
           columns.Bound(o => o.Company.CountryCode);
           columns.Bound(o => o.Company.Phone);
           columns.Bound(o => o.CompanyStatus).Title("Status");
           columns.Command(com => { com.Edit(); });
        })
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .DataSource(
           dataSource => dataSource
              .Server()
              .Sort(sort => sort.Add("Name").Ascending())
              .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.Company.Id))
              .Update(up => up.Action("UpdateCompany", "Home"))
        )
        .Editable(ed => ed
           .Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
           .TemplateName("Company")
           .Window(w => w
              .Title("Edit company")
              .Draggable()
              .Resizable()
              .Width(436)
              .Modal(true)
              .Animation(false)
           )
        )
     )
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code from your view to see what you're working with?

Comment: I added photos and code showing what I mean. The buttons should not scroll. The scrollbar should stop higher than the bottom of the window. I don't think the code I am using is relevant as I do not generate these buttons nor the window. I'm calling the ASP window option.

Comment: I'm in same situation currently. I would be glad to see solution for this.

Comment: @JaLah, I checked the solution and accepted it.  See the answer in this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve such layout, you need to handle the scrolling in your own element rather than leave it to the window. This involves some customization that may break the grid functionality, so **consider this unsupported**, as it may break without notice in the future. [Suggesting this on UserVoice](http://kendo.uservoice.com/) might get implemented officially, so it would be better in the long term.

So, in order to do that, attach a window **open event** handler:

```
var buttonWrapper = $(".k-edit-buttons");
var formContainer = $(".k-edit-form-container");
formContainer.css({
    overflow: "auto", // make the container scroll
    maxHeight: 300 // maximum height of the window content, sans the chrome
});
buttonWrapper.insertAfter(formContainer);
```

You will also need to add the styles to the button wrapper:

```
.k-edit-form-container .k-edit-buttons {
    clear: both;
    text-align: right;
    border-width: 1px 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -1em;
    padding: .6em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `Resizable()` property from the window.  I typically don't specify the `Height()` or `Resizable()` attributes for my Kendo Windows.

Comment: That makes no difference.

Comment: There is a `k-edit-form-container` class on the wrapper for the form, does anything change when you set that `height: auto`?

Comment: Doesn't change anything. I've played around a ton with changing properties in Chrome's F12 window, but no combination has quite worked.